# Suppose $ x+y+z=0 $. Show that $ \frac{x^5+y^5+z^5}{5}=\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{2}\times\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{3} $.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, symmetric-polynomials

How to show that they are equal? All I can come up with is using symmetric polynomials to express them, or using some substitution to simplify this identity since it is symmetric and homogeneous but they are still too complicated for one to work out during the exam. So I think there should exist some better approaches to handle this identity without too much direct computation.

In addition, this identity is supposed to be true:

$$ \frac{x^7+y^7+z^7}{7}=\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{2}\times\frac{x^5+y^5+z^5}{5} .$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), with $e_k$ standing for the elementary symmetric polynomials and $p_k$ for the sum of $k^{th}$ powers, and using that $e_1=0\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
p_1 &= e_1 &&= 0\\
p_2 &= e_1p_1-2e_2 &&= -2e_2 \\
p_3 &= e_1p_2 -e_2p_1 + 3e_3 &&= 3e_3 \\
p_4 &= e_1p_3 - e_2p_2+e_3p_1-4e_4 &&= 2 e_2^2 \\
p_5 &= e_1p_4-e_2p_3+e_3p_2-e_4p_1+5e_5 &&= -5e_2e_3 
\end{align}
$$

It follows that:

$$\color{blue}{\frac{p_5}{5}} = -e_2e_3 = \frac{-2e_2}{2} \cdot \frac{3e_3}{3} = \color{blue}{\frac{p_2}{2} \cdot \frac{p_3}{3}}
$$

Comment: Hhhh, nice! I think this is the method I am thinking about! But if one forget what the exact formulas of these identities(probably most of the time, hhhh) are, it would be annoying to recover each term by oneself.

Comment: @Yuchen If you remember the general form of the identity (also listed at the posted link) then, even if you forget the details, you can fairly easily write down $p_1,p_2,p_3$ then you should recognize the pattern.

Comment: Indeed! Thank you~

Answer (score 2):

Write $S_n=x^n+y^n+z^n$. Then $S_0=3$, you are given $S_1=0$ and are charged to prove that $S_5=(5/6)S_2S_3$. Define
$$F(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_nt^n.$$
Then
$$ F(t)=\frac1{1-xt} + \frac1{1-yt} + \frac1{1-zt} = \frac{3+2e_1t+e_2t^2}
{1-e_1t+e_2t^2-e_3t^3} $$
where $e_1=x+y+z$, $e_2=xy+xz+yz$ and $e_3=xyz$. Then $e_1=0$ so
\begin{align}
F(t)&=\frac{3+e_2t^2}
{1+e_2t^2-e_3t^3}=(3+e_2t^2)\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(e_2t^2-e_3t^3)^k\\
&=(3+e_2t^2)(1-e_2t^2+e_3t^3+e_2^2t^4-2e_2e_3t^5+\cdots)\\
&=3-2e_2t^2+3e_3t^3+2e_2^2t^4-5e_2e_3t^5+\cdots.
\end{align}
Therefore $S_2=-2e_2$, $S_3=3e_3$ and $S_5=-5e_2e_3$ etc.

Comment: Nice! How do you come up with the idea of constructing the very nice function $ F(t) $. It does not seem obvious to me.

Comment: @Yuchen It's a *generating function*. Generating functions are a standard way of studying sequences.

Comment: Got it. This method is awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First we can use the identities

$$ (x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(yz+zx+xy) $$

and

$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-yz-zx-xy)$$

As $x+y+z=0$, we have $x^2+y^2+z^2=-2(yz+zx+xy)$ and $x^3+y^3+z^3=3xyz$.

So, R.H.S is $-xyz(yz+zx+xy)$.

From the above results, we have

\begin{align*}
(x^3+y^3+z^3)(x^2+y^2+z^2)&=x^5+y^5+z^5+x^3(y^2+z^2)+y^3(z^2+x^2)+z^3(x^2+y^2)\\
(3xyz)(-2yz-2zx-2xy)&=x^5+y^5+z^5+x^3[(y+z)^2-2yz]\\
&\quad +y^3[(z+x)^2-2zx]+z^3[(x+y)^2-2xy]\\
-6xyz(yz+zx+xy)&=x^5+y^5+z^5+x^5-2x^3yz+y^5-2xy^3z+z^5-2xyz^3\\
-6xyz(yz+zx+xy)&=2(x^5+y^5+z^5)-2xyz(x^2+y^2+z^2)\\
-6xyz(yz+zx+xy)&=2(x^5+y^5+z^5)+4xyz(yz+zx+xy)\\
x^5+y^5+z^5&=-5xyz(yz+zx+xy)
\end{align*}

Hence, L.H.S. is also $-xyz(yz+zx+xy)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=0$, the equality is trivial. So, it is sufficient to consider $x\ne 0$.
Let $y=ax, z=abx$. Then:
$$x+ax+abx=0 \Rightarrow ab=-1-a.$$
Then:
$$\frac{x^5+a^5x^5+(ab)^5x^5}{5}=\frac{x^2+a^2x^2+(ab)^2x^2}{2}\cdot \frac{x^3+a^3x^3+(ab)^3x^3}{3} \Rightarrow$$
$$\frac{1+a^5+(-1-a)^5}{5}=\frac{1+a^2+(-1-a)^2}{2}\cdot \frac{1+a^3x^3+(-1-a)^3}{3} \Rightarrow$$
$$-a-2a^2-2a^3-a^4=(1+a+a^2)(-a-a^2).$$

Comment: Nice, I have improved your expression to make it clearer. Thanks~

Comment: Me too, thanks too.