# If $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are roots of $x^3+p x+q=0$, then $\alpha^5+\beta^5+\gamma^5=5\alpha\beta\gamma(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> If $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are the roots of $x^3+px+q=0$, show that $$\alpha^5+\beta^5+\gamma^5=5\alpha\beta\gamma\ (\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)$$

**I tried to solve using Vieta's formula, but I was getting a sign error.**

From the equation $x^3+px+q=0$,
$$\begin{align}
\sum \alpha\phantom{\beta} &= \phantom{-}0 \\
\sum \alpha\beta &= \phantom{-}p \\
\prod α \phantom{\beta} &= -q
\end{align}$$

L.H.S.
$$\begin{align}
\alpha^5+\beta^5+\gamma^5&=(\alpha^4+\beta^4+\gamma^4)(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)-\alpha^4(\beta+\gamma)-\beta^4(\gamma+\alpha)-\gamma^4(\alpha+\beta) \\
\text{(with $\sum \alpha = 0$)}\quad
&=-\alpha\beta\gamma\left(\begin{array}{c}
\phantom{+}\left(
\dfrac{\alpha^3}{\beta}
+\dfrac{\alpha^3}{\gamma}
+\dfrac{\beta^3}{\gamma}
+\dfrac{\beta^3}{\alpha}
+\dfrac{\gamma^3}{\alpha}
+\dfrac{\gamma^3}{\beta}\right)\\
+\left(
\dfrac{\alpha^3}{\alpha}
-\dfrac{\alpha^3}{\alpha}
+\dfrac{\beta^3}{\beta}
-\dfrac{\beta^3}{\beta}
+\dfrac{\gamma^3}{\gamma}
-\dfrac{\gamma^3}{\gamma}\right)\end{array}\right) \\
&=-\alpha\beta\gamma\left(\left(\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3\right)
\left(\dfrac {1}{\alpha}+\dfrac {1}{\beta}+\dfrac {1}{\gamma}\right)
-\left(\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2\right)\right) \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

Putting $\sum \alpha = 0$ in the formula 
$$\begin{align}
\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3-3\alpha\beta\gamma &=\left(\alpha+\beta+\gamma\right)\left(\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2-\alpha\beta-\beta\gamma-\gamma\alpha\right) \\
\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3&=3\alpha\beta\gamma \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Putting (2) in (1)
$$\begin{align}
&\phantom{=}\;-\prod\alpha \cdot\left(3\cdot \prod \alpha \cdot 
\dfrac{\sum\alpha\beta}{\prod\alpha}-\left(\left(\sum\alpha\right)^2-2\cdot\sum\alpha\beta\right)\right) \\
&=-\prod\alpha\cdot\left(3\cdot\sum\alpha\beta+2\cdot\sum\alpha\beta\right) \\
&=-5\cdot\sum\alpha\beta\cdot \prod\alpha
\end{align}$$

> **There is a negative sign in my solution. Please point out where I have gone wrong, or share your solution.**

Comment: I have also got this negative sign, could it be there is a typo?

Comment: Should is send you my solution?

Comment: Please post it. I too thought it as a typo. For clarification, I posted it here.

Comment: as an example, the three roots might be 1,1,-2.  The left-hand side is -30, the right-hand side is +30

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2747626/suppose-xyz-0-show-that-fracx5y5z55-fracx2y2z22-tim/2747700#2747700

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851985/big-dfracx7y7z77-big2-big-dfracx5y5z55-big2-cdot-big

Answer (score 0):

plugging $$\gamma=-\alpha-\beta$$ in the left-hand sode we get
$$-5\,\alpha\,\beta\, \left( \beta+\alpha \right)  \left( {\alpha}^{2}+
\alpha\,\beta+{\beta}^{2} \right) 
$$ (after factirization)
and the right-hand side:
$$5\,\alpha\,\beta\, \left( \beta+\alpha \right)  \left( {\alpha}^{2}+
\alpha\,\beta+{\beta}^{2} \right) 
$$